# Why is the quantum vacuum space energy density not measurable?

Tags: speed-of-light, vacuum, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I'm referring to the [vacuum catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem) unsolved problem where the Plank length quantum calculation of the vacuum space energy density:

$$
\rho_{\mathrm{P}}=\sqrt{\frac{c^{14}}{\hbar^2 G^4}} \approx 4.6 \times 10^{113} \mathrm{~J} / \mathrm{m}^3
$$

compared the actual measured value:

$$
\Lambda=8 \pi \rho_{v a c} G / c^4=\kappa \rho_{\text {vac }}
$$

where $\rho_{v a c}$  is the observable vacuum energy density currently a constant and translated to mass density,

$$
\rho_{\mathrm{F}}(m)=1.674 \times 10^{-27} \mathrm{~kg} / \mathrm{m}^3
$$

Thus, converting Joules to Kg using the current speed of light value $c$ a terrifying difference of 123 orders of magnitude!

Can it be that one possible explanation for this discrepancy, by inferring to the related equations and their relation with the speed of light, that this excess energy is actually hidden to us in someway?

Is it not possible the answer to this to be the obvious one, straight on your face, inferred by the equations, that the vacuum space has a hidden, intrinsic vibrational energy state at **superluminous** *(i.e. greater than $c$)* speed?

What other explanations are there apart of the above mentioned possible Occam's razor explanation?

Comment: The Occam's razor explanation is the anthropic principle.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Can you elaborate more on this because I fail to see the connection? Or do you mean that this is explainable by humans?

Comment: The Wikipedia article you link to talks about it.